# Writerow does not write to CSV Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm a beginner to Python and trying to create my first csv file with output from a Python script. Below is my code:

```
times = ["1AM", "2AM", "3AM"]
for time in times:
    with open("file1.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding = "utf-8") as dog:
        with open("file2.csv", 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as cat:
            reader = csv.reader(cat, delimiter=",")
            writer = csv.writer(dog, delimiter =',')
            for row in reader:
                if time in row:
                    print(time, row[0:2])
                    writer.writerow(time)
                    writer.writerow(row[0:2])
```

**EDIT:**
Expected output:

```
1AM baseball, bat
1AM tennis, racket
2AM soccer, ball
3AM fashion, show
3AM book, store
3AM kitchen, sink
```

What I'm trying to do with this code is ask Python to find all the rows that have that time, and then print out the time and the first two values of every row that contain that time. I'm trying to get this output to a csv, but my csv is completely blank and contains 0 bytes. Also, when I open it up in excel, I get a warning message about the file being a txt file, but the file extension is still .csv.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Comment: You open the output file in write mode, so it gets truncated, in every loop. If the last loop doesn't output any data, you get an empty file. Open it once before the loop.

Comment: use append mode "a" instead of write mode I agree with @ThierryLathuille

Comment: @Subham Note that using append mode would continue appending to the file between runs of the script, which is probably not what the OP expects.